# Evaluate the derivatives by implicit differentiation.

Tags: calculus

Assume all letters represent constants, except for the independent and dependent variables occurring in the derivative. $da\over db$
$$c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos(t)$$  to find *derivative*
$2ab\cos(t)$ use product rule, so $$2ab\cos(t)=2\cos(t)(a+b\frac{da}{db})$$
$$0=2a \frac{da}{db}+2b-2\cos(t)a-2\cos(t)b \frac{da}{db} $$
is it correct?, cause then i get the answer $$\frac{da}{db}=-\frac{b-a\cos(t)}{a+b\cos(t)}$$
and it is wrong :(

Comment: You made a mistake on your last step, you should be dividing both sides by $2b\cos(t) - 2a$ not $-2b\cos(t) - 2a$. Also remember to write $\frac{d}{db}$ or $'$ when calculating derivatives.

Comment: so, I will have $$\frac{da}{db} =  \frac{b+a\cos(t)}{b\cos(t)-a}$$

Comment: there should be $b-a\cos(t)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$c^2=a^2+b^2-2abcos(t)$

if you do derivative by b (asuming c and cos(t) are const )

$0=2a\frac{da}{db}+2b-2cos(t)(a+b\frac{da}{db})$

or

$0=\frac{da}{db}(2a-2bcos(t))+(2b-2acos(t))$

finaly(you made mistake in this step)

$\frac{da}{db}=\frac{a cos(t)-b}{a-bcos(t)}$

is a and b are functions of t it gets little complicated